# Turn microphone off when microphone input volume / DB is low

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio, fft

I am using this real time pitch detection program:
https://github.com/fotock/PitchDetectorExample/tree/1c68491f9c9bff2e851f5711c47e1efe4092f4de

For my purposes it work very well; it has a frequency label and when you sing a pitch the label registers a frequency and when you sing a little higher pitch the frequency label increases.

The problem is when I am NOT singing into the microphone, the frequency label still registers a frequency, usual around 70Hz, but it jumps up to 200Hz sometimes even when the mic is off.

Is there a way to have the microphone only turn on when the volume / DB is loud enough? An event listener that would only trigger when the mic receives a preset amplitude. Basically, I need an audio gate, if the DB is low, just line noise, then the mic is off.

Here is the pitch detection code from the above app - unabridged. I tried to no avail, to add vDSP code to this code and read the amplitude of the incoming frequency to turn the mic on and off.

PitchDetector.m

```
#import "PitchDetector.h"
#import <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>

#define PD_SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

@implementation PitchDetector
@synthesize lowBoundFrequency, hiBoundFrequency, sampleRate, delegate, running;

#pragma mark Initialize Methods


-(id) initWithSampleRate: (float) rate andDelegate: (id<PitchDetectorDelegate>) initDelegate {
    return [self initWithSampleRate:rate lowBoundFreq:40 hiBoundFreq:4500 andDelegate:initDelegate];
}

-(id) initWithSampleRate: (float) rate lowBoundFreq: (int) low hiBoundFreq: (int) hi andDelegate: (id<PitchDetectorDelegate>) initDelegate {
    self.lowBoundFrequency = low;
    self.hiBoundFrequency = hi;
    self.sampleRate = rate;
    self.delegate = initDelegate;

    bufferLength = self.sampleRate/self.lowBoundFrequency;    


    hann = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*bufferLength);
    vDSP_hann_window(hann, bufferLength, vDSP_HANN_NORM);

    sampleBuffer = (SInt16*) malloc(512);
    samplesInSampleBuffer = 0;

    result = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*bufferLength);

    return self;
}

#pragma  mark Insert Samples

- (void) addSamples:(SInt16 *)samples inNumberFrames:(int)frames {
    int newLength = frames;
    if(samplesInSampleBuffer>0) {
        newLength += samplesInSampleBuffer;
    }

    SInt16 *newBuffer = (SInt16*) malloc(sizeof(SInt16)*newLength);
    memcpy(newBuffer, sampleBuffer, samplesInSampleBuffer*sizeof(SInt16));
    memcpy(&newBuffer[samplesInSampleBuffer], samples, frames*sizeof(SInt16));

    free(sampleBuffer);
    sampleBuffer = newBuffer;
    samplesInSampleBuffer = newLength;

    if(samplesInSampleBuffer>(self.sampleRate/self.lowBoundFrequency)) {
        if(!self.running) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(performWithNumFrames:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:newLength]];
            self.running = YES;
        }
        samplesInSampleBuffer = 0;
    } else {
        //printf("NOT ENOUGH SAMPLES: %d\n", newLength);
    }
}


#pragma mark Perform Auto Correlation

-(void) performWithNumFrames: (NSNumber*) numFrames;
{
    int n = numFrames.intValue; 
    float freq = 0;

    SInt16 *samples;
    if (PD_SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.1")) {
        @synchronized(self) {
            samples = malloc(sizeof(SInt16)*numFrames.intValue);
            memcpy(&samples, &sampleBuffer, sizeof(samples));
        }
    } else {
        samples = sampleBuffer;
    }

    int returnIndex = 0;
    float sum;
    bool goingUp = false;
    float normalize = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j<n; j++) {
            sum += (samples[j]*samples[j+i])*hann[j];
        }
        if(i ==0 ) normalize = sum;
        result[i] = sum/normalize;
    }


    for(int i = 0; i<n-8; i++) {
        if(result[i]<0) {
            i+=2; // no peaks below 0, skip forward at a faster rate
        } else {
            if(result[i]>result[i-1] && goingUp == false && i >1) {

                //local min at i-1

                goingUp = true;

            } else if(goingUp == true && result[i]<result[i-1]) {

                //local max at i-1

                if(returnIndex==0 && result[i-1]>result[0]*0.95) {
                    returnIndex = i-1;
                    break; 
                    //############### NOTE ##################################
                    // My implemenation breaks out of this loop when it finds the first peak.
                    // This is (probably) the greatest source of error, so if you would like to
                    // improve this algorithm, start here. the next else if() will trigger on 
                    // future local maxima (if you first take out the break; above this paragraph)
                    //#######################################################
                } else if(result[i-1]>result[0]*0.85) {
                }
                goingUp = false;
            }       
        }
    }

    freq =self.sampleRate/interp(result[returnIndex-1], result[returnIndex], result[returnIndex+1], returnIndex);
    if(freq >= self.lowBoundFrequency && freq <= self.hiBoundFrequency) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [delegate updatedPitch:freq];
        }); 
    }
    self.running = NO;
}


float interp(float y1, float y2, float y3, int k);
float interp(float y1, float y2, float y3, int k) {

    float d, kp;
    d = (y3 - y1) / (2 * (2 * y2 - y1 - y3));
    //printf("%f = %d + %f\n", k+d, k, d);
    kp  =  k + d;
    return kp;
}
@end
```

Here is the AudioControll.m class that initializes that microphone - unabridged. Looking at other examples of turning the mic on and off according to DB, I tried many frameworks like Audio Queue Services and the Accelerate Framework to no avail.

AudioControll.m

```
#import "AudioController.h"

#define kOutputBus 0
#define kInputBus 1

@implementation AudioController
@synthesize rioUnit, audioFormat, delegate;


+ (AudioController *) sharedAudioManager
{
    static AudioController *sharedAudioManager;

    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (!sharedAudioManager) {
            sharedAudioManager = [[AudioController alloc] init];
            [sharedAudioManager startAudio];
        }
        return sharedAudioManager;
    }
}


void checkStatus(OSStatus status);
void checkStatus(OSStatus status) {
    if(status!=0)
        printf("Error: %ld\n", status);
}

#pragma mark init

- (id)init
{
    OSStatus status;
    status = AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, (__bridge void*) self);
    checkStatus(status);

    // Describe audio component
    AudioComponentDescription desc;
    desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
    desc.componentFlags = 0;
    desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
    desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

    // Get component
    AudioComponent inputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

    // Get audio units
    status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(inputComponent, &rioUnit);
    checkStatus(status);


    // Enable IO for recording
    UInt32 flag = 1;

    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(rioUnit,                                   
                                  kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, 
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                                  kInputBus,
                                  &flag,
                                  sizeof(flag));
    checkStatus(status);


    // Describe format
    audioFormat.mSampleRate= 44100.0;
    audioFormat.mFormatID= kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags= kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket= 1;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame= 1;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel= 16;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket= 2;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame= 2;

    // Apply format
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(rioUnit, 
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Output, 
                                  kInputBus, 
                                  &audioFormat, 
                                  sizeof(audioFormat));
    checkStatus(status);

    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(rioUnit, 
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, 
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Input, 
                                  kOutputBus, 
                                  &audioFormat, 
                                  sizeof(audioFormat));
    checkStatus(status);

    // Set input callback
    AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
    callbackStruct.inputProc = recordingCallback;
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void*)self;

    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(rioUnit, 
                                  kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback, 
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Global, 
                                  kInputBus, 
                                  &callbackStruct, 
                                  sizeof(callbackStruct));
    checkStatus(status);


    // Disable buffer allocation for the recorder
    flag = 0;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(rioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_ShouldAllocateBuffer, kAudioUnitScope_Global, kInputBus, &flag, sizeof(flag));


    // Initialise
    UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
    status = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(category), &category);
    checkStatus(status);

    status = 0;
    status = AudioSessionSetActive(YES);
    checkStatus(status);

    status = AudioUnitInitialize(rioUnit);
    checkStatus(status);

    return self;
}

#pragma mark Recording Callback
static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                                  UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                                  UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                                  AudioBufferList *ioData) {

    AudioController *THIS = (__bridge AudioController*) inRefCon;

    THIS->bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    THIS->bufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = sizeof(SInt16)*inNumberFrames;
    THIS->bufferList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1;
    THIS->bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData = (SInt16*) malloc(sizeof(SInt16)*inNumberFrames);

    OSStatus status;

    status = AudioUnitRender(THIS->rioUnit, 
                             ioActionFlags, 
                             inTimeStamp, 
                             inBusNumber, 
                             inNumberFrames, 
                             &(THIS->bufferList));
    checkStatus(status);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [THIS.delegate  receivedAudioSamples:(SInt16*)THIS->bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData length:inNumberFrames];
    }); 

    return noErr;
}



-(void) startAudio
{
    OSStatus status = AudioOutputUnitStart(rioUnit);
    checkStatus(status);
    printf("Audio Initialized - sampleRate: %f\n", audioFormat.mSampleRate);
}

@end
```

Comment: I think it's not possible, I had some kind of experience working with IR motion detector (when I was programming in embedded system), my task was to turn off motion detector when there is no motion, but you need to turn it on, right? for turning on I need a motion (but motion detector is turned off), I resolved this issue by nice algorithm, if there is no motion my motion detector sleeps for 10 seconds, then wake ups and checks for motion (if motion is detected, it's starts for working with timeout) if no motion, then it sleeps for 10 seconds.

Comment: Just check the size of the largest peak in the spectrum and if it's below a certain threshold then return a pitch of 0 (or -1 perhaps).

Comment: Thanks Paul R, could you show how that could be done? I've worked with this code and tried many things in the last few days but I am a total noob when it comes to audio analyses. Bins and samples with imaginary numbers makes my think stack over heat!